# Trying to understand what part of this Node.js code is responsible for directing my POST request to the mongoose/mongodb server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

so I'm new to programming and I'm taking a Udemy course on web development. I'm following along with the course and there's something I don't understand in this code. I have a MongoDB database set up and I'm using Node.js with the NPM package manager. I can clearly see how the server.js file is linked to the database:

```js
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');
```

I can clearly see how server.js is pulling in the POST request from the frontend application in the `app.post()` section.

What I can't see is, once the POST has been pulled into the the file's logic, what in `server.js` is directing the json info, in the POST, into the MongoDB database? It's getting in there. It's there when I use `mongosh` to look directly in the database but I don't understand how it's actually getting in. Thank you all for the help.

**server.js:**

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/swag-shop');  
    var Product = require('./model/product');
    var WishList = require('./model/wishlist');
    const { request } = require('express');
    
    
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    
    app.post('/product', function(request, response) {
        var product = new Product();
        product.title = request.body.title; 
        product.price = request.body.price; 
    
    
        product.save(function(err, savedProduct) {
            if (err) {
                response.status(500).send({error:"Could not save product"})
            } else {
                response.status(200).send(savedProduct);
            }   
        });
    });
    
    
    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log("Swag Shop API running on port 3000...");
    });
```

**product.js:**

```js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    var product = new Schema({
        title: String,
        price: Number,
        likes: {type: Number, default: 0}
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', product);
```

**wishlist.js:**

```js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const product = require('./product');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;
    
    var wishList = new Schema ({
        title: {type: String, default: "Cool Wish List"},
        products: [{type: ObjectId, ref:'Product'}]
    });
    
    module.exports = mongoose.model('WishList', wishList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Mongoose` package to connect to MongoDB server and to perform various queries. So, when you do `product.save()`, `Mongoose` will create a new record in database.

Answer (score 0):

```
    product.title = request.body.title;   
    product.price = request.body.price;
```

request. is a function and it's saying product.title equals make a request for the body.title, etc.

The product.save then saves that information.